# How to get OSM data using Overpass API from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have the following code for requesting map data from OSM:

```
$.ajax({
    url:
        'https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?' + 
        '[out:json][timeout:60];' + 
        'area["boundary"~"administrative"]["name"~"Berlin"];' + 
        'node(area)["amenity"~"school"];' + 
        'out;',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true
}).done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
}).fail(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log( "error" );
}).always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
});
```

When I test the request on Overpass Turbo, it runs without any issues, but when preforming this request in a JavaScript, I always get the error:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" lang="en"/>  <title>OSM3S Response</title></head><body><p>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: Key expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: '!', '~', '=', '!=', or ']'  expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: Value expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: ',' or ']' expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: Key expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: '!', '~', '=', '!=', or ']'  expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: Value expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: ',' or ']' expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: static error: For the attribute "k" of the element "has-kv" the only allowed values are non-empty strings. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: static error: For the attribute "k" of the element "has-kv" the only allowed values are non-empty strings. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: Key expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: '!', '~', '=', '!=', or ']'  expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: Value expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: parse error: ',' or ']' expected - '%' found. </p><p><strong style="color:#FF0000">Error</strong>: line 1: static error: For the attribute "k" of the element "has-kv" the only allowed values are non-empty strings. </p></body></html>"
```

There must be something wrong with the way I do the request, but I cannot figure out what could be wrong with it.

How do I get the positions of all schools in Berlin from a JavaScript?

I also tried using `$.getJSON()` but that didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you use in your example seems to be incomplete: it should read ...`interpreter?data=[out:json]`.... i.e. the **data=** part was missing.

As a reference you can also put your query in overpass turbo and simply click on Export -> raw data directly from Overpass API to get to a working URL. Maybe try this first with wget and if it works out ok, put the URL in your Javascript code.

Maybe you also want to study a bit, how overpass turbo does the (POST-based) calls to Overpass API: please see https://github.com/tyrasd/overpass-turbo/blob/master/js/overpass.js#L581 for details.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't refresh the page before posting my own answer. Wow that link is a lot of unreadable code :D but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Without a library, we have to `POST` a query formatted in [OverpassQL](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL).

This example will retrieve restaurants into a rather small bounding box *bottom_left/top_right* `48.865,2.25,48.9,2.27` somewhere in Paris.

```js
(async () => {
  const api = await fetch('https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body:"[out:json];node(48.865,2.25,48.9,2.27)[amenity=restaurant];out;"
  });
  const answer = await api.json();
  console.log(answer);
})()
```

[List of `amenity` keys](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:amenity) matching most common POI like *pharmacy, parking, veterinary* ...

---

This API is easily overloaded, we have to pass in smalls areas, and we better have to use a timeout. Unexpected errors are common, we have to handle them in our apps.

But warning the error response is not in JSON, but in XML, could require some try/catch over a [XMLparser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML).

EQ:

> Error: runtime error: open64: 0 Success /osm3s_v0.7.58_osm_base
> Dispatcher_Client::request_read_and_idx::timeout. The server is
> probably too busy to handle your request.

Examples complex queries in the overpassQL language https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example